# Getting Semester Averages with Grades using files in Python

Tags: python, file

I want to write code that will take a file of grades and return an average of it all, so homework average, project average, quiz average, and semester average. In the file it would have a column at the start which would be the "legend" to the code. Here's an example of what the grade file would look like:

```
last, first, hw, hw, project, quiz, hw, hw, hw, quiz, hw, hw, project
#It won't also be in this order, that's what makes this hard!
Cat, Figaro, 57, 58, 71, 93, 56, 86, 90, 99, 55, 99, 88
#Not a real name lol, there would also be A LOT more names and grades
```

I can't figure out how to make it iterate through the legend column and the grades column to correctly grade the file. Here's the formula for grading:

```
semester average = homework average * 0.2 + quiz average * 0.2 + project average * 0.6.
```

Here's what I have so far. I'm terrible with files so I only know how to call a column.

```
def start():  
  gb_data = open('gb_data.txt','r')
  header = gb_data.readline()
  print(header.strip())
```

the strip() at the end would get rid of the \n that happens when you change lines. This prints the first column of the file but I want to iterate through it and identify the legend, not just print it. Here's what the return file would look like:

```
Cat, Figaro: hw avg = 71.57, quiz avg = 96.0, proj avg = 79.5, sem avg = 81.21
```

Please help! This is NOT homework and is simply a project to understand files better, my name is Scarlett btw.

Comment: Try to read the file as a CSV file. Here is a tutorial for that: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ginkul's answer couldn't cover to handle multiple row of values
so I try to write code more generally like below:

```
def get_header():  
    gb_data = open('gb_data.txt','r')
    header = gb_data.readline()
    return header.strip()

def get_content():  
    gb_data = open('gb_data.txt','r')
    content = gb_data.readlines()
    del content[0]
    return content

hw_pos = []
project_pos = []
quiz_pos =  []

header_list = get_header()
header_list = header_list.split(", ")
header_list_index = enumerate(header_list)
for index, target in header_list_index:
    if target == "hw":
        hw_pos.append(index)
    elif target == "quiz":
        quiz_pos.append(index)
    elif target == "project":
        project_pos.append(index)

content_list = get_content()

avg_dict = {}

for element in content_list:
    element = element.strip().split(", ")

    name = element[0] + ', ' + element[1]
    hw_avg = sum([int(element[i]) for i in hw_pos]) / len(hw_pos)
    project_avg = sum([int(element[i]) for i in project_pos]) / len(project_pos)
    quiz_avg = sum([int(element[i]) for i in quiz_pos]) / len(quiz_pos)
    avg_dict.update({name:(hw_avg, project_avg, quiz_avg)})


for name, avg in avg_dict.items():
    print(name, "hw avg : ", round(avg[0], 2), "project avg : ", round(avg[1], 2), "quiz avg : ", round(avg[2], 2))
```

### save your all output to another text file

```
for name, avg in avg_dict.items():
    with open("avg.txt", "a") as f:
        dataline = name + " hw avg : " + str(round(avg[0], 2)) + \
        " project avg : " + str(round(avg[1], 2)) + " quiz avg : " + str(round(avg[2], 2)) + "\n"
        f.write(dataline)
```

Comment: This works amazing! I have one request, I want to add the results to a different file. I have code to add stuff to a different file, but don't know how to add it to your answer.

Comment: The code is ``` averages = open('avfs.txt', 'w')
averages.write('#Stuff to add ')
averages.close()```

Comment: @idontcare you mean you want to add all results in another txt file?

Comment: Hey! I have oneeee small question, how do I add the semester average?

Comment: Sorry, but I also need the sem average. Would the str(round(avg[2], 2)) work with semester average? Because I put in the equation but for some reason it's very off.

Comment: @idontcare you can calculate sem avg easily with values which we already got :  `round(avg[0]*0.2 + avg[1]*0.2 + avg[2]*0.6, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT This code is incorrect for multiple rows

You could try the following code:

```
def start():
    with open('gb_data_.txt', 'r') as f:
        keys = f.readline().strip().split(',')
        values = f.readline().strip().split(',')
        last = values[0]
        first = values[1]

        hw = [int(v) for k, v in zip(keys, values) where 'hw' in k]
        hw_avr = sum(hw) / len(hw)

        project = [int(v) for k, v in zip(keys, values) where 'project' in k]
        project_avr = sum(project) / len(project)

        quiz = [int(v) for k, v in zip(keys, values) where 'quiz' in k]
        quiz_avr = sum(quiz) / len(quiz)

        sem_avr = hw_avr * 0.2 + quiz_avr * 0.2 + project_avr * 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at pandas. It's best to give your columns unique column names, though.

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_avg(row):
    hw_avg = (row['hw_1'] + row['hw_1'] + row['hw_1']) / 3
    # fill in as needed
    quiz_avg = ...
    proj_avg = ...
    return hw_avg * 0.2 + quiz_avg * 0.2 + proj_avg * 0.6

# read your data
df = pd.read_csv('your-file.csv')
# 'apply' a function to each row (axis=1) in a dataframe,
# add all results to a new column called 'semester_avg'
df['semester_avg'] = df.apply(get_avg, axis=1)
```